# How to change the field of time-series to `double` data type when inserting `null` value failed in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question about inserting data into Apache IoTDB. When I try to insert `null` value into a field of time series, an error message prompted that `Msg: 507: Fail to insert measurements [ds] caused by [Path [root. testl.pl.` W3:XX:11:C1`.ds] does not exist`. I tried to set the value to an empty string, then this value is inserted succeed. So what should I do if I want to set this field to `double` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this time series in Apache IoTDB does not exist before, you cannot directly use `insert null` command because the data type cannot be inferred from the history recorded. If you have created it in advance using `create timeseries` command, no error will be reported when inserting `null` value, so you can try to create this time series first.